# why @SpringBootTest does not load the context

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-test, spring-boot-test

I was using `@SpringBootTest` annotation to run integration tests. but it suddenly stopped working! it does not load the context anymore, it just runs as a unit test and all injected beans are null. I do not remember what change I made. so, what can cause this problem?

- the Spring Boot version is 2.3.
- The context is loaded by adding `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

the problem was solved. the `@Test` annotation was not the correct one! It should be `org.junit.jupiter.api.Test`. stupid IDE auto import!

Comment: Took me two weeks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need to specify `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` as `@SpringBootTest` itself contains `@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)`.

Also make sure that you still have Application class with `public static void main(String[] args)` annotated with `@SpringBootApplication` under `/main/java/` directory in the same module.

Comment: I can run the application (there is a `public static void main(String[] args)` of course)